# This action will also remove the following packages [all my apps]

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

So I'm using Kubutu and I'm trying to install Wine to run Photoshop, but when I try to install wine via `sudo apt install wine` or via KDE's Discover software center thing it gives me a popup telling me that the following packages will be removed. These packages include Firefox, WPS office, telegram-desktop, and a whole bunch of other stuff I installed via the termial.

**Obviously it should absolutely not be doing this, can somebody tell me why this is happening?**

Listed below is some information I think might be important:

- I run the latest Linux kernel (not the latest Ubuntu kernel) because I need it for driver support.

```
$ uname -a
Linux LinuxIsPower 5.2.2-050202-generic #201907231250 SMP Tue Jul 23 12:53:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- There might be something wrong with my sources.list file?

```
deb http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ disco restricted main universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security multiverse main restricted universe
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
```

- I have tried `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, everything is up to date.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease            
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97,5 kB]            
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                     
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease                        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hvr/ghc/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Fetched 97,5 kB in 1s (132 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
```

Comment: first of all your sources.list is incomplete. I don't see disco-updates

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `apt install --simulate wine`. sudo is not needed. This command will NOT install anything.

Comment: Well, this is not the result I was hoping for, but after a restart I was unable to recreate the error with neither `apt install --simulate wine` nor `apt install wine`, so I guess I'll mark this thread as answered when AskUbuntu allows me to.

Comment: @nobody Oh thanks, I did not realize that. Guess it's time to go fix that...

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the suggestion, that'll be helpful the next time I have a problem. Sadly? I can't seem to reproduce the error after I shutdown my computer for a lunch break so I guess the mystery ends here.

Comment: aptitude why,why-not may give you some insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the problem no longer being reproducible, I'd suggest that this is the kind of message you'd get if you were trying to install a package with a massive incompatibility -- for instance, if the version of Wine you were attempting to install needed to uninstall KDE Desktop, you'd get a warning that it was going to uninstall everything that depended on KDE Desktop -- which might be a list of a hundred or more packages, and due to cascading dependencies, might well include packages you wouldn't think of as being part of the desktop environment.

This kind of massive uninstall can happen when you try to install a package that depends on a newer or older version of some libraries, for instance -- especially if the dependency is written to a single, specific version on one side or the other.  That, in turn, can happen if you try to make too many installations (especially major ones) without at least logging out and back into Ubuntu (restarting the hardware usually isn't required).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clear explanation!